# Decrypt authenticated cipher while still encrypting

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, aes-gcm

Normal AES-GCM generates an authentication tag at the end of encryption. I want to decrypt it while it is still being encrypted. This would be useful to send, encrypt, receive and decrypt a large file (for example) in one go.

This would also be useful for other things like for video streams or encrypted calls. **How could I do that?** Switching to CBC seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. This is rather a programming question, belongs to SO. There is already similar question arisen before, there. See this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57382238/1820553), for example.

Comment: @kelalaka this question is 65% crypto, 35% programming. The question you linked is a different issue.

Comment: In one of the question in SO, I've proposed, splitting the file into parts than adding the TAG into the next block. as block-chain. Also, If you look at Netflix, it uses TLS with AES-GCM where TLS transfers only $2^{14}$-byte framing.

Comment: See also this answer [Real time video stream AES encryption with authentication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62190/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka: "...I've proposed, splitting the file into parts than adding the TAG into the next block. as block-chain..." Can you find that? I've been looking around and haven't been able to.

Comment: The answer on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422153/1820553).

Answer (score 0):

AES-GCM can be used as a as stream cypher by splitting the input to multiple blocks along with a nonce. However using AE for each block may not be an efficient technique.

- See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/DLyC8UIJXa4) topic
- Also read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9539/authenticated-encryption-mode-for-stream-cipher) post.

Comment: I don't have to decrypt every block instantly, I could split it up, for example frame by frame for video streaming. But how would I do that? Should I create a new individual IV and Tag for each new "Packet"?

Comment: @user11227590 I think there's a counter value separate from the IV. Iterate the counter value.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - If you have the time, consider quoting/summarizing some of the content from the links in your answer; Links expire, and if that happens it can turn a useful answer into a non-useful one. Plus, a more detailed answer will probably net you more up votes.

Comment: @Natanael neither javas Cipher nor C#s AuthenticatedAesCng have got  counter value.